# How to get gridview clickable cell data value to new page aspx

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have two columns in a GridView where every cell of 1 column is hyperlinked.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvBlogList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id"  
AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"> 
<Columns> 
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="id" 
            HeaderText="Blog id" NavigateUrl="detailspage.aspx" /> 
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle> 
    </asp:TemplateField> 
</Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

How can I get cell value in 2nd page as a session variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="gvBlogList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
        <Columns>

            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="id" HeaderText="Blog id"  NavigateUrl="detailspage.aspx" />
            
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

Comment: Welcome to SO, but please edit your question to post your codes. Hard to view codes in comment. thanks.

Comment: Hi Raptor, please have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

As per the what I understand from your question, you want to catch the value of the cell that is clicked, store it in session and make it accessible on the page that have redirect to. This is possible and you can try a flow like this :

You can use the GridView's inbuilt method `onRowCommand` in this case to generate a server side event and you can then identify which cell was clicked and lastly, you can get its value by index. The below code is a demonstration that you can try and manipulate as per your requirement. This is a sample where a Linkbutton is used in Gridview and on the click of it, its value is fetched.

You can also try to use the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` properties if you want to assign that particular control a value that you may use at the server side.

```
protected void Grd1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
   string value = lnk.Text;
}
```

And for storing it in `Session`, you just have to make use of `Session["yourVarName"] = value;`. And this value can be accessed on the other page.

Hope this helps.